# SQL server query file is opening up in notepad and displaying weird characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a sample of the text when I try opening the file:

" ÞÆÖ·Öþ´½LuÓÏ$À€ì@‚Ø6§“*àþ‡ºb7ÝVç¹chEˆþç¹Þâµ(æ…Õeï/ÉñÍªV€Œçh¼Û}n®]øÇÿÉÂ|»‡YKY?~Vè»Z4gâ™4Öýb)-Ð«­±©…CÂXÀþ„£•˜¼Ü¢Ó[Þhà^û+™ÙÛ "

another sample (in a different language as appears):

" 웞럖ﻖ಴봇界쿓쀤艀㛘鎧蟾抺��楽ޕㅄ�劓㕥�笒䍖꒠触紳葔ᶤ樖涴뫖镵Ç䁥轈䟹㵪퓢㏈䮗듵⽢︠ꩬﱫ댧꫷⨿풘富摔�ꁼ쓨꟡⛰꘻㛾嶇뼟꜠퓎쐻笤薣㢏仮데ⅽ쯠ꅕًጇ�饂耰挟ɐ⾶开㵴곚齻㢈䮢둁㯉᠐摇跰⢄쵣䅘�疯揌荎〶ಾ‏⼍删䎈鋅垫䩍ꔘ䌦曳꫙흼魊ᰏཧ릝獆 "

I'm not sure what this is and how this came to be, but when I try opening my SQL query files they open up in a notepad and they display these weird characters that looks like its written in different languages. Is there any way or chance I can convert the text into what I originally had as my script?

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's your file extension? .sql?

Comment: who gave you this file? you have to ask them first.. :)

Comment: these are my files that I created and wrote, yes the extension is .sql